# How to use polymer client side routing with app engine endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, polymer, polymer-1.0, google-cloud-endpoints

My application makes use of polymer for front-end and app engine endpoints (Java) for my backend. For reasons I don't understand, my endpoints client is not loading and I could see some strange url requests failing which seem to have been modified by app-route in my polymer front-end. I see the following failures:-

> https://(app-id).appspot.com/_ah/api/images/gweld_logo.png - Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>
> https://(app-id).appspot.com/src/_ah.html  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

My polymer code is based on the starter kit provided by polymer-cli. Here's the code for my-app.html:-

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
.
.
<template is="dom-if" if="{{!userSignedIn}}">
  <div class="container">
    <paper-card image="/images/gweld_logo.png" alt="(Company Name)" class="logo">
       <div class="card-content horizontal layout center-justified">
                    Company Portal
       </div>
       <div class="card-actions horizontal layout center-justified">
         <google-signin label-signin="Sign-in"
                                   client-id="(client-id)"
                                   scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
                                   signed-in="{{userSignedIn}}">
         </google-signin>
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  </div>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{userSignedIn}}">
.
.
  <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
     <a name="view1" href="/view1" paper-drawer-toggle>View One</a>
  </iron-selector>
  .
  .
  <iron-pages
        selected="[[page]]"
        attr-for-selected="name"
        fallback-selection="view404"
        role="main">
      <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
      <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
  </iron-pages>
.
.
</template>
.
.
Polymer({
  is: 'my-app',

  properties: {
    page: {
      type: String,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      observer: '_pageChanged'
    }
  },

  observers: [
    '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)'
  ],

  _routePageChanged: function(page) {
    this.page = page || 'view1';
  },

  _pageChanged: function(page) {
    // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
    var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
    this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
  },

  _showPage404: function() {
    this.page = 'view404';
  }
```

In my-view1.html, I make use of google-client-loader element to load the client for my app engine endpoints api.

Here's how I defined static-files in appengine-web.xml:-

```
    <static-files>
      <include path="/service-worker.js"/>
      <include path="/bower_components/**.js"/>
      <include path="/*.json"/>
      <include path="/index.html"/>
      <include path="/src/**.html"/>
      <include path="/bower_components/**.html"/>
      <include path="/bower_components/**.css"/>
      <include path="/images/*.png"/>
      <include path="/**.ico"/>
   </static-files>
```

I have the following in my web.xml:-

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>(values removed here)</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

While I want index.html to be loaded for all requests, I don't want any request to load the client library intercepted by my client side routing. Please let me know how I can solve the above issues. Also, what is the correct practice to use client side routing (app-route) with app engine endpoints?

Comment: Please share more detail. What are the URLs of the requests failing? With what status? Are there log messages? The JS client load shouldn't even hit your backend at all, since you're using v1 of the frameworks.

Comment: I added the error messages I see in the log. Note that my website works fine in firefox but it fails in chrome with the errors above. My website sometimes works on the dev box in chrome. I am not sure what's going on and I don't know how to debug this issue further.

Comment: Seems like an issue with Polymer or how you are using it. Can you post more detail on how you're configuring app-route?

Comment: I added the details of my polymer code.

Comment: Why was my question given a negative vote without an explanation? If I made a mistake, please let me know so that I can rectify it.

Comment: @saiyr Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: Sorry, Polymer is a bit outside of my expertise. I'm an Endpoints engineer and it looks like a Polymer issue as Endpoints isn't receiving URLs properly. I would however recommend that you update to the [new framework](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java).

Comment: Thanks @saiyr. I moved to the new framework but I was still running into the same issue. While trying to solve this problem, I deleted service-worker.js and that worked! Now I am trying to figure out why that worked and how I can fix the issue with service-worker.js so that I don't have to delete it. It would be great if someone from the polymer team could take a look at this question.